# Angular Class Default variable type?

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular Component I am confused with the title property, please some one clarify this

```
export class AppComponent {
  title:string = 'app works!';
}
```

why title is not declared using let or const or var?
What is default type of title Prop?

Comment: Quick question! Are you using typescript?

Comment: Default type is `any`

Comment: @31piy: Yes. Typescript and angular 2

Comment: That's why this syntax takes place. In typescript, you can declare a variable in class using `name:type = value` syntax. [Ready to learn more?](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Comment: @31piy: I didn't understand Doc fully. Can you elaborate this part. I am not native english speaker

Comment: Please [go through this](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/typescript/). It will teach you the basic syntax of TypeScript.

Comment: @Antguider it's like in Java, title is a property/field of class AppComponent.

Answer (score 0):

Default type is any. The following code prints 1

```
export class AppComponent { title = 1; }
```